# Fluent Validator doesn't throw error when it should

Tags: c#, .net, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I have the following models (all code simplified)

```
public class BiddingTierSetViewModel
{
   public List<BiddingTierViewModel> BiddingTiers { get; set; }
}

public class BiddingTierViewModel
    {
        public decimal StartValue { get; set; }
        public decimal? EndValue { get; set; }
        public decimal StepAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a validator for the set

```
public class BiddingTierSetViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BiddingTierSetViewModel>
{
public BiddingTierSetViewModelValidator(IValidator<BiddingTierViewModel> biddingTierViewModelValidator)
{
    RuleFor(x => x.BiddingTiers).SetCollectionValidator(biddingTierViewModelValidator);
}
}
```

And for each element in the collection

```
public class BiddingTierViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BiddingTierViewModel>
    {
        public BiddingTierViewModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.StartValue).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0M);
        }
    }
```

Now, in my test I set the startvalue to be less than zero

```
var validator = new BiddingTierViewModelValidator();
            var biddingTiers =
                new List<BiddingTierViewModel>() 
                { 
                    new BiddingTierViewModel() 
                    {
                        StartValue = -1,
                        EndValue = 100
                    }
                };
  biddingTierSetViewModelValidator = new BiddingTierSetViewModelValidator(
                validator);

            biddingTierSetViewModelValidator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(b => b.BiddingTiers,
                biddingTiers);
```

When I run my test I get the error

```
FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidationTestException : Expected a validation error for the property BiddingTiers
```

Why is my validator not throwing an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think you can't get errors when you use SetCollectionValidator and you don't  validate the "parent" of the collection (here, you try to validate the collection, but not the parent (`BiddingTierSetViewModel`)

See this [post](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/277676)